# Import Adobe After Effect animation to xcode

Tags: ios, rendering, after-effects, lottie, bodymovin

I have some trouble importing my animation from Adobe After Effect to Xcode and web.

I have made a character and rigged it with the Duik-plugin. I made the annimation i would like to get into xcode, and rendered it to JSON using bodymovin.
I have an image of the animation here:

[image]

Then i take the rendered JSON file and import it into my project. I use the Lottie-ios framework (https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios). 
In my viewDidLoad() i use this code to show the animation:

```
    let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "Velkomst")
    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 
    self.view.frame.size.width, height: 250)
    view.addsubview(animatedView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    animationView.play()
```

But as you can see below, the result is pretty... Wierd...
[image]

I also created a demo file when i rendered the after effect aniation. On the demo-website it is a little closer to the animation. But still not there.
[image]

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? Cause i cant figure it out :-(

Comment: But why you are not exporting this animation into png sequence?

Comment: Arh, the square is moving in the animation like a 'movie'. So i cant just export into png

Comment: I mean png sequence. It's like a bunch of multiple "png"s for each frame of your animation.

Comment: That sound smart! How do i do that?

Comment: Check this (note that in your case you need to choose PMG sequence with RGB with Alpha channel) : https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6CSPTuRjgwU

Comment: Thank you very much! But how is that way for the performance for the app? I got 59 pictures for this small animation, isn't that pretty hard for the iPhone?

Comment: I don't think so ;)